# Wrong Calculation by User-Defined SQL-Function

Tags: sql, postgresql, user-defined-functions, postgresql-9.4

I have a function defined by

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.div(dividend INTEGER, divisor INTEGER)
    RETURNS INTEGER
    LANGUAGE 'sql'
    IMMUTABLE
    LEAKPROOF
    STRICT
    SECURITY DEFINER
    PARALLEL SAFE
    AS $BODY$
        SELECT ($1 + $2/2) / $2;
    $BODY$;
```

It should calculate a commercial rounded result. Most of the times, it does the job. I don't know why, but `select div(5, 3)` gives me the correct answer while it doesn't when one parameter is calculated by an aggregate, e.g. `select div(sum(val), 3) from (select 1 as val UNION SELECT 4) list` is sufficient to trigger that.
How can I fix `div`? I don't want to cast every input.

BTW, using `SELECT (cast($1 as integer) + cast($2 as integer)/2) / cast($2 as integer);` as the definition of `div` didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allow floats as parameters, then explicitly cast at the calculation, otherwise you have an implied conversion whilst passing the parameter.

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_div(dividend FLOAT, divisor FLOAT)
>     RETURNS INTEGER
>     LANGUAGE 'sql'
>     IMMUTABLE
>     -- LEAKPROOF -- not allowed at dbfiddle.uk
>     STRICT
>     SECURITY DEFINER
>     PARALLEL SAFE
>     AS $BODY$
>         SELECT --($1 + $2/2) / $2;
>            (cast($1 as integer) + cast($2 as integer)/2) / cast($2 as integer)
>     $BODY$;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select my_div(sum(val), 3) 
> from (select 1 as val UNION SELECT 4) x
> ```
>
> ```
> | my_div |
> | -----: |
> |      2 |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=115a96ec9a00ecfeac16913276968fd8)*

Answer (score 2):

Change the name of the function.

The function [div(numeric, numeric)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html) is a builtin Postgres function and there is an ambiguity which function you want to call:

```
select div(5, 3)           -- calls your function public.div(integer, integer)
select div(5::bigint, 3)   -- calls pg_catalog.div(numeric, numeric)
```

In the second case the arguments have to be resolved and the system function is chosen as first.

Note that the function `sum(integer)` gives bigint as a result.

Comment: So awful I didn't think about that. Thank you.